# Router link doesnot working on mouseenter event

Tags: reactjs, react-router

router link mouseenter event is not working.when i put the cursor on router link it does not change the routes. my router link working properly but i want to working on mouseenter event. please suggest me some way how can i solve this problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
    import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
    import ToggleDisplay from 'react-toggle-display';
     import './App.css';
    import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    import Example from './Example.js';
    import About from "./About.js"; 
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onNavigateHome = this.onNavigateHome.bind(this);
      }

      onNavigateHome() {
        this.props.history.push('/about');
      }
      render() {
        return <div className="App">
            <Router >
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/about" onMouseEnter={this.onNavigateHome.bind(this)}>
                      About
                    </Link>
                  </li>

                </ul>

                <hr />

                <Route exact path="/" component={Example} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              </div>
            </Router>
            <Example />
          </div>;
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router's Link is designed to be a click event not a mouse enter event. You can do it another way around by using state change when you do a mouse enter. Following is a pseudo code.

```
  changeState(){
    if (!this.state.entered) {
      // window.location.href='/newResource';
      this.props.history.push('/about');
    }
    this.setState({ entered : !this.state.entered });
  }

  render() {

    return (<Router>
      <span role="link" onMouseEnter={this.changeState}>
        Link
      </span>
    </Router>);
  }
```